# Question list missing left margin/padding

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The question list has shifted over to the left into the margin, Firefox 87.0.0-rc.1 (Build #2015799099) on Android 10.

Main site:

[image]

Meta:

[image]

Comment: Posted from phone, feel free to flesh out while I can't make it to a PC

Comment: I guess we can at least the other bug where the questions have too much padding

Comment: Yeah... that's broken. I'm reverting the change that's causing this.

Comment: So we're back to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361403/incorrect-indentation-for-questions-loaded-via-ajax)? I guess I prefer it.

Comment: The same on meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362416/non-alignment-of-questions-in-every-sub-tab-under-the-questions-tab.

Comment: It is time to shift to the left anyway. So this is [meta-tag:status-bydesign]

Comment: [Uh, again?](https://i.imgur.com/wsuA0Wh.png)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I reverted the change that caused this. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the report!

[image]

Comment: [CSS is awesome](https://i1.wp.com/css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/css-is-awesome.jpg)

Comment: That image is what I want to show to people who say CSS is easy.

Comment: Ok, that picture made me laugh out loud :) So recognisable. slightly less of an issue if you can use flex or grid.

Comment: It appears some other bug may have happened in the meantime... http://i.stack.imgur.com/UWnrt.png now the fields are all showing inline.

Comment: @TylerH I don't think that's new. Or, at any rate, not a related issue to this one.